# Firebase Crashlytics as pod dependency

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, crashlytics

I have a library project on which I'm replacing the Fabric Crashlytics SDK with the new Firebase Crashlytics SDK.

Before the upgrade the Podfile on my library contained

```
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

and the Podspec

```
spec.dependency "Crashlytics"
```

After the upgrade the line in the Podfile was replaced with

```
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
```

and in the Podspec with

```
spec.dependency "Firebase/Crashlytics"
```

Compiling the library project itself works, however when using it as a Cocoapods library from another project I get `No such module 'Firebase'` on `import Firebase` in the library code.

Looking at what Cocoapods creates in the project importing my library I see that the library has `Firebase-CoreOnly-Crashlytics` as a dependency which in turns has `FirebaseCore` and `FirebaseCrashlytics` as dependencies.

This is in line with what I would expect yet it doesn't compile.

Comment: Similar problem reported here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4777

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5368#issuecomment-386021996) workaround:

```
s.xcconfig = { 'SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS' => '$(PODS_ROOT)/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources' }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my App settings hope help you to solve this issue

1- the first thing i did is to update the podfile from pod 'Firebase/Crash' to pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'

2 update the debug symbolopen [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/munJM.png)

add the code run crashlytics run code [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3IDV.png)

3 - clean your build

4 - rerun your code